# Pass Trigger values to WpfApplication

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, triggers

I have a trigger that access my wpf application. Here's the code:

```
SET @q_id = (SELECT q_id FROM INSERTED)
SET @acct_no = (SELECT acct_no FROM INSERTED)
SET @loan_num = (SELECT loan_num FROM INSERTED)
```

Then after the value is set, the trigger will then access the wpf application. The problem is that I don't know how to get the values set by the trigger.

Comment: How do you execute your application? Maybe you can pass your values like start parametrs of app? Also you can store your values in the table, and read this table in your app.

Comment: Triggers typically don't have any interaction with any code outside the database - they're very much "internal" to the database... what you *can* do is set some column values to whatever you need them to be (or insert a row into a specific table) and then read out that table from your WPF app after the transaction is committed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will just be using a formless exe file that will be included in the Task Scheduler for a specific time.